# JSF Validator not found

Tags: validation, jsf

I have created a validator in my project in the package "com.travstar.validators" called EmailValidator.

Content of the class:

```
package com.travstar.validators;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.FacesValidator;
import javax.faces.validator.Validator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;

@FacesValidator("emailValidator")
public class EmailValidator implements Validator
{
    private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\." +
            "[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*" +
            "(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;

    public EmailValidator()
    {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException
    {

        matcher = pattern.matcher(value.toString());
        if (!matcher.matches())
        {

            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Email validation failed.", "Invalid Email format.");
            msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

and I implement the email validation like this:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" width="100%">
                    <h:outputText value="Email Address"></h:outputText>
                    <h:inputText id="emailAddress" value="#{passengerDetailsBean.contactDetails.emailAddress}" styleClass="input-block-level" placeholder="" required="true">
                        <f:validator validatorId="emailValidator"></f:validator>
                    </h:inputText>
                    <h:message for="emailAddress" styleClass="alert alert-error" />
                </h:panelGrid>
```

This is more or less exactly like a tutorial I found online, but I haven't been able to get it working.

The moment I hit the page, the following exception is thrown:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Unknown validator id 'emailValidator'
```

I'm using JSF 2.1, so as far as I know I am not required to fiddle with the faces.config.xml

Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: To avoid the obvious, did you properly clean/rebuild/redeploy/restart the project and server? That registration in faces-config.xml is not necessary if you already use the annotation. On an unrelated note, since half 2010 non-Latin characters are allowed in domain names and thus also email addresses. Your regex pattern which only matches Latin characters is therefore severely broken.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks - yes, I did clean and redeploy.

The regex pattern is a simple placeholder for now - once I get it working I will look for a more forgiving one on regexlib.com :)

Comment: Then I don't know. `ClassNotFoundException` clearly means that class is not in classpath. Provided that you didn't make any typos, this can only mean that project wasn't properly built/deployed, or that you're simply not running the code you think you're running. Dive in the server's deploy folder and browse if you see a `EmailValidator.class` at the expected place. The exception suggests that it's not there.

Comment: @BalusC I checked. The file seems to be in the right place. I decided to try my luck and just popped the validator tags into the faces-config.xml and it started working. I'm quite puzzled what I was doing wrong, since I made very sure which version of JSF I was running.

I will close this question now. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Apparently the target server is agressively caching its deploy/work folder and not immediately noticing any external changes. Which one are you using? Does it have kind of "development" and "production" stage setting? Set it to development. Edit: by the way, you don't need to yell the answer in the question. Just post the answer as an answer the normal way.

Comment: It was set to production. I am now able to use the validators without having to do anything to the faces-config.xml

Thanks BalusC, I think you can put that into an answer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the target server is agressively caching its deploy/work folder and not immediately noticing any external changes. Which one are you using? Does it have kind of "development" and "production" stage setting? Set it to development.

Comment: It was set to production - I set it to dev and it's workign fine now, thanks a bunch!